# Retrieving a document containing a subset of documents matching a query and the total number of matches

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

How would one query a collection to retrieve a limited number of documents matching a query and the amount of documents matching the said query at the same time.

I'm looking for a result like this one:

```
{
    result : [
        {
            _id:null,
            total:734, //there are 734 documents matching the query
            page:[ //limited to 3
                {_id:"...", someValue:30000}
                {_id:"...", someValue:30400}
                {_id:"...", someValue:31900}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to get this for paging purposes.

Comment: It looks like you want some sort of "statistics" on your results, such as a total count and then a limited "current page". Your best approach is to do this with multiple queries and manipulate the object to return.

Comment: @NeilLunn Currently I first get the count then I do the paginated request, but I believe these 2 operations should be doable in one query.

Comment: Was there something in the supplied answer that does not answer your question?

Comment: Nope just that I got over my head in other projects before implementing and testing the generic solution based on your answer. High five!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To further explain, what you seem to be trying to do is implement "paging" with a total result count using the aggregation framework. This is not a good idea, so I will show you why:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Some query to match results
    { "$match": { /* some query */ } },

    // Then group to get the count -- OOPS! 
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "page": { "$push": /* the documents */ }, // essentially the problem
        "total": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},

    // Then unwind -- oh dear!
    { "$unwind": "$page" },

    // Then skip and limit
    { "$skip": 100 },
    { "$limit": 25 }

    // And group back again :-<
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "total": { "$first": "$total" },
        "page": { "$push": "$page" }
    }}
])
```

The really horrible thing there aside from all the pipeline processing is that you are "pushing" every result onto an array. You have to in order to get the total count.

Then there is also no real concept of "slice" for an array in the aggregation framework. What you need to do is be stuck with the [**`$skip`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/) and [**`$limit`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) pipeline stages in order to get your "current page" of results.

There is no other way to do this, except of course to realize the the aggregation framework itself is not the tool for this. You want to do one query to count the total results and another for your current page of results. Which is exactly how we've been doing it with SQL databases for years.

There are some things to be aware of when using mongoose though:

```
// Avoiding the indentation creep

var queryDoc = {};
async.waterfall(
    [
        function(callback) {
            Model.count(queryDoc,function(err,count) {
                callback(err,count);
            }
        },
        function(count,callback) {
            var query = Model.find(queryDoc);
            query.skip(100).limit(25).exec(function(err,page) {
                callback(err,{ "total": count, "page": page });
            });
        }
    ],
    function(err, result) { 
        if (err) throw err; // or handle
        console.log( result ); // or res.send or whatever
    }
);
```

Ideally you really should be looking at range queries rather than using "skip" and "limit" or generally otherwise just looking for the last "seen" value to be "greater than" for forward only paging.

If you have to use the aggregation framework for your query results then fine, but do it in the same way. Trying to get total counts and then "page" out the results is just horrible.